# Revive Li-Ion Battery White MacBook (2006)

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

I have a White MacBook (2006) with a new battery (2013) that I accidentally let sit discharged for too long (a few weeks). Now the battery doesn't work. If I leave the battery in the laptop while plugged in, it gets very hot as if it is trying to charge but won't. So, to be safe I am running the computer with the battery pulled. Anyone know any ways to revive the new dead battery, or am I stuck buying a new one again?

Comment: Can you say more about how it "doesn't work?"  What do the battery lights do when you press the button?

Comment: None of the lights light up when I push the button. I think I will simply buy another battery. Has anyone else had a lithium ion battery pass beyond the place where they can charge back from? Or is this a situation you've never heard of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a lithium ion battery is drained and left to sit for an extended period of time uncharged, it can go into a "sleep" state that does not enable a recharge by standard charging methods. 
I found this info at http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/charging_lithium_ion_batteries

"Li-ion should never be discharged too low, and there are several safeguards to prevent this from happening. The equipment cuts off when the battery discharges to about 3.0V/cell, stopping the current flow. If the discharge continues to about 2.70V/cell or lower, the battery’s protection circuit puts the battery into a sleep mode. This renders the pack unserviceable and a recharge with most chargers is not possible. To prevent a battery from falling asleep, apply a partial charge before a long storage period."

Answer (score 1):

That shouldn't happen at all. I think the battery itself has a defect. Because the battery wasn't charged before you got it, for a much longer time than two weeks. Because, the seller has, obviously, stored the battery himself for a long time.

I would recommend to return the battery immediately. Otherwise you risk damage to your laptop.

Comment: The battery worked fine for about a year. Then I discharged it (used the laptop unplugged) and forgot to plug it in for a few weeks (we were moving, traveling, etc.).